# Shrink mounted linux partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to shrink a Linux partition to make room for a Windows 7 installation coming up, but GParted (running within Linux) will not allow me to shrink the mounted /dev/sda2 partition.

Is there any way around this, or must I boot into GParted from a USB drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must boot from a USB drive or a Live CD so that the partition isn't being used. You can get a bootable GParted Live CD from http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Once you have the ISO, you can use [Unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make a bootable USB drive form the ISO.